# p:messages not displaying inside a dialog in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, message, display

I have a p:messages inside a dialog in Primefaces 6 but this element is not being displayed with any content. It just doesn't diplay in the screen. I'm Setting the error message in a bean but it does not display the message. I want the error message to show inside the dialog. I've tried updating the p:messages inside the commandbutton and in the Bean. Here is the code:

Bean:

```
public void persist() {
    boolean error = false;
    addErrorMessage("schedule_summary_error_message", "FUMBLE! Something went wrong! Try it again.", null); // Added this line so the error message can show no matter what but it still doesn't show.

    for (int i=0; i < newMatchups.size(); i++) {
         if (!matchupService.persist(newMatchups.get(i)))
             error = true;
    }

    if (error) {
        addErrorMessage("schedule_summary_error_message", "Something went wrong! Try it again.", null);
    } else {
        reloadCurrentMatchups();
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('newScheduleDialog').hide()");
    }
}


private static void addErrorMessage(String clientId, String summary, String detail) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.addMessage(clientId, new FacesMessage(Constant.ERROR, summary, detail));
}
```

xhtml:

```
<p:dialog id="newScheduleDialog" appendToBody="true" responsive="true" widgetVar="newScheduleDialog" header="Creating the game schedule" 
position="center top" closeOnEscape="true" width="60%" modal="true" style="overflow-y:auto;max-height:100%">
<p:ajax event="close" oncomplete="PF('createScheduleWizard').loadStep(PF('createScheduleWizard').cfg.steps[0], true)" />
   <h:form id="schedule_form">
      <p:wizard id="createScheduleWizard" widgetVar="createScheduleWizard" showStepStatus="false" flowListener="#{scheduleWizard.onFlowProcess}" showNavBar="false" >
        <p:tab id="summaryTab" title="Summary">
            <p:messages id="schedule_summary_error_message" for="schedule_summary_error_message" showDetail="true" showSummary="false" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />                                                     
            <p style="text-align: center;" class="sansation_bold16">Summary </p> 

            <ui:include src="../pages/matchup_carousel.xhtml" />
            <p:commandButton value="Save and publish schedule" id="saveButton" widgetVar="saveButton" actionListener="#{matchupBean.persist}"
                              style=" -webkit-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px; margin-top:20px"/>
        </p:tab>

    </p:wizard>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen before to use the id in "for" attribute with the same id of the element itself. Try use a different id (form's id maybe) on the messages's "for". Try:

```
<p:messages id="schedule_summary_error_message" for="schedule_summary" showDetail="true" showSummary="false" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
```

and add the message tied to the form's id:

```
addErrorMessage("schedule_summary", "Something went wrong! Try it again.", null);
```

Comment: Just tried this but it didn't work. The message still doesn't show. The reason I added this p:messages is to display an error message whenever we run into an exception in the database transaction or any other exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the javascript piece of code to show the dialog after adding error message which is missing in your code.

Comment: That was just the piece of code relevant for the problem. At this point, the dialog is already displaying.

Comment: Ok. Since the commandbutton triggers ajax call by default you need to update the messages component using update attribute on the commandbutton in order to update the messages after the ajax completes.

Comment: Just tried that but it didn't work but in theory we shouldn't have to do that because we have the autoUpdate="true" on the messages:    <p:commandButton value="Save and publish schedule" id="saveButton" widgetVar="saveButton" actionListener="#{matchupBean.persist}"           style=" -webkit-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px; margin-top:20px" update="league_tab_view:schedule_form:schedule_summary_error_message"/>

Comment: If the message is indeed getting added in the backing bean, then its update issue on the page. You verify it using sysout statements.. then can you try to use update="@all" on the command button.